# Formal sounding word or phrase for "punish"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In my writing I encounter topics about regulations and I am forced to use the word "punish" very frequently. The tone of my writing should be formal / professional, and I am at my wit's end as to how to introduce much needed word variety -- seeing as all the synonyms that the thesaurus and my brain can think of do not have the right level of formality.

- spank
- chastise (formal, but now its overkill)
- crack down

This is merely for the general case, but for illustrations sake, consider:

> The regulator _______ the company citing insufficient due diligence.

### Question

My last iota of hope hinges on some phrase that retains a formal style that has the appropriate meaning. Thesauruses are not always robust to such phrases, so perhaps the greater community here will have some ideas.

Comment: Maybe reprimand (although I infer a minor transgression from it)

Comment: Maybe “sanction” will work for you.

Comment: I do like sanction.  Also: penalize, admonish, call out, scold, reprimand, issue a formal reprimand, write (the company) up, rap (the company) on the knuckles, pound, castigate, discipline, issue a rebuke, lambaste.  Of these, "call out" seems the most informal.

Comment: How about "The regulator cited the company for insufficient due diligence."

Comment: You can't just ask us to "fill in the blanks" without telling us ***exactly*** what you're trying to say. A "regulator", for example, could do many different things - ranging from issuing a ***warning***, through handing out ***fines*** or punishment right up to closing down a business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Castigate** can be used. It is a formal synonym for *punish*.
[Dictionary Defenition:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/castigate)
***cas·ti·gate*** - **verb** *(used with object)*
1. To criticize or reprimand severely
2. To punish in order to correct.

Comment: This would be a better answer with a link to (and an excerpt from) the definition of *castigate* from a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

At the most formal level (used in parliamentary procedure): [censure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/censure)

> 1 : a judgment involving condemnation unorthodox practices awaiting
>   the censure of the city council
>
> 2 : the act of blaming or condemning sternly The country faces
>   international censure for its alleged involvement in the
>   assassination.
>
> 3 : an official reprimand The lawyer's misconduct resulted in a letter
>   of censure from the judge.

Source: merriam-webster.com

Other good options include: Rebuke, Reprimand, Reproach